# Importing android library to JAVA project on Eclipse

Tags: java, android

Can I import android library such as android 2.3.3 which is included android.jar on it into a JAVA project on Eclipse? How can I do it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can, and I don't think you should. Android's classes are made for Android mobile devices so you shouldn't use them outside of that context. Do you mind detailing exactly what your project is?

Comment: I got the project from web (I don't really remember where). the first one is java project, and the other one is android project. import. android was exist on a class in the java project, but it cannot recognize it.

Comment: I guess what you should do then is import that as an existing Android project, not as a Java project. If you're using Eclipse, go to File > New > Android Project, then select the radio button for "Create project from existing source." Then point it to the directory where the project is.

Comment: Was that what you were looking for?

Comment: Sorry for troubling you with many questions, but the androidManifest file doesn't exist so I cannot create a new Android project. Is there any way for me to convert Java project into android project?

Comment: No, you can't run an Android project like an ordinary Java project or vice versa. Unlike Java applications, Android is UI-intensive and uses Activities (unless you're running an Android service) instead of the console, JFrames, etcetera. Android projects, on the other hand, use a lot of classes not native to the Java API. If you really want to run the project you downloaded you can attempt to write the manifest file yourself. Whoever uploaded that project's kind of an ass though for not including something required to run your app.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why would you do that... but yes, you can.

Go to: Project properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add External Jar, then choose the .jar file you need, for instance:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-8\android.jar
```

Now your Java project can reference any Android-specific class.

Comment: Most probably if you're using the latest http client from Apache for android. As the default client included in Android before Android 6.0 is actually a fork of the old Apache client. this android jar inclusion is just to compile that client. :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess I have come across the same problem as Karate_dog, though I'm not sure how similar it is.

Here is what I did:
Go to project properties, select android, and check Android 2.3.3 and press OK. You are done.

Now you will see all the previous error notifications have gone and android API and libraries have been added to your project (I assume this is regarding an android project which running on eclipse ide.)

Answer (score 0):

Activate proper android nature,  and your project has android libraries on compile path.
You may also add android libraries from maven central:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

But keep in mind,  that those libraries are good for compiling only - all classes are neutered and contain only stubs throwing runtime exception - you wull be unable to use them in tests unless you use mocking